# PHPMailer - php openssl returning IP address instead of host name as CN?

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-openssl

I've used PHPMailer before, but haven't run into this issue - it appears as though OpenSSL is returning the IP address for `smtp.google.com` instead of the hostname. This would cause TLS to not work right?

It's not like the traffic is being manned in the middle because it's getting the right IP address, but it should be `CN=smtp.gmail.com` instead of `108.177.112.XXX`.

I know a common problem is if the traffic is being sent somewhere else, but this isn't the case - it's the correct server it's just that `PHPMailer` is receiving back the IP instead of the hostname.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MJpX.png

`CentOS 7.6`

`PHP 7.2.13`

`PHP OpenSSL 1.0.2k`

I expect the debug output from PHPMailer to match both CN's as smtp.gmail.com

Comment: The common name *is* smtp.gmail.com, but you used an IP address instead of the domain name to connect to the server. Don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text into the question next time.

Comment: And especially don’t post images in imgur as they track everything without consent.

Comment: use localhost in place of IP address

Comment: I didn't though - 

$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';